# I would like to use this in an align environment. Has anyone know how can I do it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, align

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, amsmath}

\newcommand{\highlight}[2][black]{\tikz[baseline, anchor=base]{\node[inner sep=2mm](A){$#2$};
    \draw[#1] (A.north east)--(A.south east)--(A.south west);
    \draw[#1] ([shift={(.1,.5)}]A.south east)--([shift={(-.5,-.1)}]A.south east);
    \draw[#1] ([shift={(.1,.3)}]A.south east)--([shift={(-.3,-.1)}]A.south east);
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
   \highlight{a_{\rho}=\dfrac{V^2}{\rho}} 
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

I use this to highlight a result.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses `tikzmark` and requires naming a `tikzmarknode` at the beginning and another at the end. After the `align` environment, call the `\highlight` macro with the nodes you named.

You must compile twice.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\highlight}[3][orange!70]{\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{
    \draw[very thick, shorten >=-3mm, #1] ([shift={(.2,.1)}]#3.north east)--([shift={(.2,-.2)}]#3.south east)--([shift={(.2,-.2)}]#3.south east-|#2.west);
    \draw[thick, #1] ([shift={(.3,.3)}]#3.south east)--([shift={(-.3,-.3)}]#3.south east);
    \draw[#1] ([shift={(.3,.1)}]#3.south east)--([shift={(-.1,-.3)}]#3.south east);
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
x&=1\\
y&=2\\
\tikzmarknode{A}{a_{\rho}}&=\tikzmarknode{B}{\dfrac{V^2}{\rho}}
\end{align*}
\highlight{A}{B}

\end{document
```

Answer (score 2):

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, mathtools}
\pgfqkeys{/tikzHighlight}{
  .code=\pgfqkeys{/tikzHighlight}{#1},
  .unknown/.code=\pgfkeyssetevalue{/tikzHighlight/color}{\pgfkeyscurrentname},
  color/.initial=black, text/.initial=black,
  node/.style={
    text=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikzHighlight/text},
    anchor=base,overlay=false,inner sep=\fboxsep+.5\fboxrule, outer sep=+0pt,
    append after command={(\tikzlastnode.north east)|-(\tikzlastnode.south west)
      {[shift=(\tikzlastnode.south east),rotate=45]
        (-2mm,1mm) edge[thin] (2mm,1mm) (-3mm,2mm) edge (3mm,2mm)}}
  },
  path/.style={
    overlay,thick,line cap=round,draw=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikzHighlight/color}},
}
\newcommand*\highlight[1][]{%
  \gdef\tikzHighlightOptions{#1}%
  \tikzHighlightBoxedInt}
\newcommand*\tikzHighlightBoxed[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline,/tikzHighlight/.expand once=\tikzHighlightOptions]
    \draw[/tikzHighlight/path]node[/tikzHighlight/node]{#1};}
\MakeAboxedCommand\tikzHighlightBoxedInt\tikzHighlightBoxed

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \highlight                                   {a_{\rho} &= \frac{V^2}{\rho}} \\
  \highlight[orange!70]                {\frac{V^2}{\rho} &= a_{\rho}} \\
  \highlight[path/.append style={rounded corners=2pt}]{E &= mc^2}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Your tikz answers always are elite and highly technical. If you don't mind, may I cite here an unanswered question of mine? I can delete this comment if you don't appreciate such a request.

Comment: @Diaa Sure, maybe I can take a look at it. But I doubt I've got an answer nobody else could have thought of.

Comment: Many thanks for your consideration. You can have a look at it here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/622325/2288. Thanks again!